# Using jQuery to automatically add class only to gif images in WordPress database

Tags: images, jquery

When adding any image to a page or post, Wordpress is automatically adding a paragraph tag

as parent holding the image as follow:

```
<p><img src="my-image.gif" alt=""></p>
```

I'd love to find a solution to apply a specific classname only to gif images. The example above would thus result in:

```
<p><img class="gif-class" src="my-image.gif"></p>
```

Comment: This is not a WordPress question, but rather a selector question. You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231839/specific-image-extension-selector-in-css-or-jquery

Comment: Generic PHP/JS/SQL/HTML/CSS questions are better asked at Stack Overflow

Comment: @markratledge sorry for that. What can I do now?

Comment: Ask at Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
$('img[src*=".gif"]').addClass('gif-class');
```

Thanks to @BrianFegter